# How to promote external sites besides my own in search results?

Tags: seo, google

I have a site which, after fixing a lot of SEO issues, is now doing fairly well in Google search result rankings; the problem is I would like some related pages on other people's websites to show along with my own pages. For example, if I were to search for my name and the first page is full of links to pages on my website, how can I get Google to rank other relevant links like my StackOverflow profile higher?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to get a single site to rank high on Google and getting multiple sites is simply more work.

In essence, it is the same activity repeated for each site. In other words, just like you worked to get your site ranked high, you have to promote the other ones too. Of course, if the other ones are not yours entirely, your mission is harder. Luckily, most factors that rank a website are external.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [brandyourself](http://brandyourself.com), which can help get pages about you ranked higher or lower (it gives moderate success in my experience).  Also, make sure your StackOverflow profile links to your site; and that your site links to it.